# Return array with all data in key

Tags: php, arrays, preg-grep

I have this array `$allYearData`
Now i´d like to split it into 12 parts, seperated by month.
So i use PHP `preg_grep()` with a `foreach` loop to search for data.

```
foreach($allYearData as $key){
    $janData[] = preg_grep("/^2015-01-.*$/", $key);
}
```

How can i fetch all data in each key?
As you can see in `$janData` i get empty keys where there is no hits. And then only the date if there is a hit.

I´d like `$janData` to be a new array with key 0 to contain the first hit and all data/values in that key. Like $allYearData but only with the hits from preg_grep.

**$allYEarData:**

```
Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( 
    [id] => 7811
    [objekt_element] => 23050-121-1_3105
    [objekt_nr] => 23050-121-1
    [element_nr] => 3105
    [vart] => B.Avf
    [vem] => Blå
    [anteckn] => 
    [datum] => 2015-09-29 18:00:19
  ) 
  [1] => Array ( 
    [id] => 7812
    [objekt_element] => 23050-121-1_3107
    [objekt_nr] => 23050-121-1
    [element_nr] => 3107
    [vart] => B.Avf
    [vem] => Blå
    [anteckn] =>
    [datum] => 2015-09-29 18:00:22
  )
  [2]...
```

**$janData**

```
Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( )
  [1] => Array ( )
  [2] => Array ( )
  [3] => Array ( )
  [4] => Array ( )
  [5] => Array (
    [datum] => 2015-01-16 04:17:01
  )
  [6] => Array ( 
    [datum] => 2015-01-16 04:16:57 
  )
  [7]
```

**I´d like $janData to be filled**

```
Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( 
    [id] => 7811
    [objekt_element] => 23050-121-1_3105
    [objekt_nr] => 23050-121-1
    [element_nr] => 3105
    [vart] => B.Avf
    [vem] => Blå
    [anteckn] => 
    [datum] => 2015-01-16 18:00:19
  )
```

Comment: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$key in you foreach is array, so select where is a date you want to hit and use $key to add to result array.

```
foreach($allYearData as $key){
    if (preg_grep("/^2015-01-.*$/", $key['datum']){     
        $janData[] = $key;
    }
}
```